# How can I set an absolute path for include function in php above the working directory?

Tags: php, include, relative-path

I am running a script from

```
/wp-content/themes/currenttheme/chat.php
```

I want to include in the above php another one located in

```
/forum/chat/index.php
```

The index.php includes its own files

I already tried

```
$root = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];
include($root."/forum/chat/index.php");
```

but I get this error

> Warning: require(D:/My Dropbox/xampp/htdocs/lib/custom.php) [function.require]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in D:\My Dropbox\xampp\htdocs\forum\chat\index.php on line 17
>
> Fatal error: require() [function.require]: Failed opening required 'D:/My Dropbox/xampp/htdocs/lib/custom.php' (include_path='.;\My Dropbox\xampp\php\PEAR') in D:\My Dropbox\xampp\htdocs\forum\chat\index.php on line 17

(the index.php also includes some files, but the /forum/chat is ommited somehow in the path)

then I tried

```
$path   = getcwd();
$myfile = "/forum/chat/index.php";
include ($path.$myfile);
```

and got this error:

> Warning: include(D:\My Dropbox\xampp\htdocs\forum/forum/chat/index.php) [function.include]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in D:\My Dropbox\xampp\htdocs\wp-content\themes\currenttheme\chat.php  on line 24
>
> Warning: include() [function.include]: Failed opening 'D:\My Dropbox\xampp\htdocs\forum/forum/chat/index.php' for inclusion (include_path='.;\My Dropbox\xampp\php\PEAR') in D:\My Dropbox\xampp\htdocs\wp-content\themes\currenttheme\chat.php on line 24

Answer (score 1):

There is no problem with index.php. It is being included.
The error message says about custom.php file

Just use the same `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` technique for the `custom.php`

you have to add /forum/chat manually as there is no path to be omitted

Comment: custom.php    is included in    index.php    and it works fine when launched any way except when I try to do the above mentioned inclusion

Comment: @Baros So what? Why not to repair it the way I told you?

Answer (score 0):

Something wrong with:

```
include('../../../forum/chat/index.php');
```

?

There are all sorts of reasons why the code you've published will fail.

C.

Comment: When I use it as you wrote it, I get the second error.  

It starts working only if I add another / before the first .. but now I get the first error.

Comment: using relative path is always bad idea.

Comment: I agree. But I have no choice    'Warning: include() [function.include]: http:// wrapper is disabled in the server configuration by allow_url_include=0'    and    'Warning: include() [function.include]: URL file-access is disabled in the server configuration'

Comment: @Col. Shrapnel - There's no such thing as 'always' when it comes to questions of programming style - although I admit that **usually** using relative paths other than '.' are a bad idea.

Answer (score 0):

use this.

```
require_once(ABSPATH.'forum/chat/index.php');
```

here ABSPATH = WordPress physical root directory path with trailing slash